# Can't Update Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates

My software center has been jammed for about 2 weeks. When i click install on updates the progress bar goes immediately halfway...and then waits for the end of the universe.

How can I troubleshoot this? I've never used Ubuntu, just assume that I'm clinically Amish.

Edit: Here's the results of running `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` after following Azendale's answer:

```
sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for: 
Hit:1 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [95.7 kB]
Hit:3 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Get:4 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Get:5 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [332 kB]
Get:6 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [328 kB]
Fetched 850 kB in 3s (275 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-signed-generic
  linux-signed-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice apparmor bamfdaemon bind9-host chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
  compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default
  compizconfig-settings-manager cups-browsed cups-filters
  cups-filters-core-drivers dkms dnsutils eog file-roller firefox
  firefox-locale-en flashplugin-installer fontconfig fontconfig-config fwupd
  gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0
  gnome-calendar gnome-font-viewer gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common
  gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-sudoku gnome-system-monitor gnupg gpgv
  gtk2-engines-murrine ifupdown isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common kpartx
  kpartx-boot libaccountsservice0 libapparmor-perl libapparmor1
  libappstream-glib8 libbamf3-2 libbind9-140 libcompizconfig0 libcupsfilters1
  libdecoration0 libdfu1 libdns-export162 libdns162 libdrm-amdgpu1
  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-dev libdrm-intel1 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm-radeon1:i386
  libdrm2 libdrm2:i386 libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-dev libfontconfig1
  libfontconfig1:i386 libfontembed1 libframe6 libfwupd1 libgbm1 libgcrypt20
  libgcrypt20:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgl1-mesa-dev
  libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
  libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles1-mesa libgles2-mesa
  libgles2-mesa-dev libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common libharfbuzz-icu0
  libharfbuzz0b libidn11 libidn11:i386 libisc-export160 libisc160 libisccc140
  libisccfg140 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 liblwres141 libmetacity-private3a
  libmysqlclient20:i386 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common
  libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnm0 libnma-common libnma0 libosmesa6
  libosmesa6:i386 liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0
  libp11-kit0 libp11-kit0:i386 libpam-systemd libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler58
  libpython3.5 libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib libsmbclient
  libssl1.0.0 libssl1.0.0:i386 libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386 libudev-dev
  libudev1 libudev1:i386 libunity-core-6.0-9 libwayland-egl1-mesa libwbclient0
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 libxatracker2 light-themes
  linux-libc-dev mesa-common-dev mesa-vdpau-drivers metacity metacity-common
  mtools mysql-common network-manager network-manager-gnome openssh-client
  openssl oxideqt-codecs-extra p11-kit p11-kit-modules p11-kit-modules:i386
  poppler-utils python-compizconfig python3-distupgrade
  python3-software-properties python3.5 python3.5-minimal samba-libs
  snap-confine snapd software-properties-common software-properties-gtk sudo
  suru-icon-theme systemd systemd-sysv thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support
  thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us ubuntu-artwork
  ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-mobile-icons ubuntu-mono
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-session udev
  unity unity-schemas unity-services vino xdiagnose xserver-xorg-video-intel
185 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/208 MB of archives.
After this operation, 410 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 234231 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic (4.4.0-24.43) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-24-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-24-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-24-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-24-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_lU1drr/lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_lU1drr/lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012': not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic (4.4.0-24.43) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012': not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-28-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-28-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-28-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-28-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_sMUWeu/lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_sMUWeu/lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012': not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012': not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try running `sudo apt install -f`, which may fix your problem

Answer (score 2):

Try opening your terminal and running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. It will prompt you for your user password. You should now be able to see any errors that are occurring. You can use those to ask a more specific question regarding those errors.

Comment: sudo apt-get update at the end says this...E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pyroom-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: alot of stuff went by ending with when I tried sudo apt-get dist-upgrade E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) However now the progress bar goes to the very end,  then stops...progress i guess?

Comment: That just means that you have some apps in your sources.list that need to be removed. Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` for those repos and remove them. That's old software that doesn't have a xenial release.

Comment: :~$ /etc/apt/sources.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied
:~$ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/: Is a directory
:~$ 

heres the results from checking those sources lists @Matt O

Answer (score 2):

You might be seeing this bug (I ran into this myself after a new install): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1583845

You can use the `top` command on a terminal to see if this is your problem. "appstreamcli" will show up using 100% cpu.

Quick fix is to remove the /usr/bin/appstreamcli file and then update to the newest version:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/appstreamcli
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install appstream
```

Comment: Thx Matt, I went and checked using top but couldn't find appstreamcli. Would it hurt to try it anyway?

Comment: If you aren't sure you can `sudo mv /usr/bin/appstreamcli /usr/bin/appstreamcli.disabled` that way you can rename it back if it turns out that you already have the updated package. I suspect that if you aren't seeing appstreamcli in your `top` listing that you have a different issue. Let us know what the output from `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` looks like.

Comment: I went ahead and tried your solution David, thanks, It gave me some very familiar error codes such as "failed to fetch" and "E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead." and finally E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) what do these mean? Ive seen them whenever i try to install or update anything. @David

Comment: It worked for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, start by opening the dash:

[image: Ubuntu Dash Button]

Search for Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: Dash search for Ubuntu Software Center]
[image: Software Center start screen]

Move your mouse cursor to the top of the screen, select "Edit" and then select "Software Sources".

[image: Software Sources menu item]

Go to the "Other Software" tab. Try unchecking each box to the left of each entry. (Don't worry, you can repeat this process and turn a few on at a time once you have updates working to figure out which one(s) are causing your problems and should stay off. So what we are doing here doesn't have to be permanent.)
[image: Other Software tab]

Click close. You will likely be prompted to update the package list and/or enter your password.

[image: Authentication Dialog]

After that, you should see (if you click on the

[image: Progress/Tasks tab]

tab/icon) they package list updating:

[image: Progress/Tasks page]

If that does finish successfully, then you should now be able to install updates normally now!

Edit:
You said you are still getting errors about signature problems. Open up the dash, search for terminal, and open it.

Put this in:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then copy the output, edit your original question, and add the output from the terminal on the end. We'll work through it from there. A reinstall shouldn't be necessary.

Edit:
Ok, it looks like there is something a little weird going on with the kernel packages. You could take the output from the terminal and make it a new question, with a title of something like "Apt update trouble with linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic", which would make it more likely someone more knowledgeable than I will see an answer your question. But I will also try to guess what we should try next.

Can you try running this in a terminal (and again editing your question to add the output to the end):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I'm not sure what order you'll have to do those in, but it doesn't hurt to do them more than once, so you can try the commands in both orders if need be.

Comment: Im afraid the results are the same, Ive been told I have "messed up signatures" whatever that means... Ive been recommended a complete reinstall, but my question on how to do so was put on hold as unclear X.x in fact this sites asinine policies have been holding me back for months @Azendale

Comment: When you are asking for help, please don't just mention just part of the error message, please edit your question and copy the whole error message. It really helps us know what exactly is wrong.

Comment: There we go one big heap of terminal gibberish, dig in :D I managed to get passed the sites bureaucracy by deleting 1 letter in each link, gotta love loopholes. @Azendale

Comment: Apollo, I think you should now be able to post links (I think you get that when you get a reputation score of 10 or better.) Creative workaround though!